# How do I compile googleTestLibrary on QNX 6.5.0?

Tags: build, googletest, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I want to compile google Test Library on QNX. But I did not success. I tried everything. Can be seen my compilation errors below

Is someone share to **libGoogleTest_g.a** and **libGoogleTest.a** file for me ?

```
D:/ETCT_PROJECTS/CommonLibrary/Test/ETCCommon/Common/QNXUnitTests/../../../../GoogleTestLibrary/lib\libgoogleTest_g.a(gtest-all.o): 
In function `_M_initialize_dispatch<const char* const*>':
/usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/c++/4.4.2/ext/new_allocator.h:87: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
D:/ETCT_PROJECTS/CommonLibrary/Test/ETCCommon/Common/QNXUnitTests/../../../../GoogleTestLibrary/lib\libgoogleTest_g.a(gtest-all.o): 
In function `operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >':
/usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/c++/4.4.2/bits/basic_string.h:2506:
 undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
D:/ETCT_PROJECTS/CommonLibrary/Test/ETCCommon/Common/QNXUnitTests/../../../../GoogleTestLibrary/lib\libgoogleTest_g.a(gtest-all.o): 
In function `ValueHolder':
/usr/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/c++/4.4.2/ext/new_allocator.h:87: undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
D:/ETCT_PROJECTS/CommonLibrary/Test/ETCCommon/Common/QNXUnitTests/../../../../GoogleTestLibrary/lib\libgoogleTest_g.a(gtest-all.o): In function `~DeathTestImpl':
/home/emres/GoogleTest/./src/gtest-death-test.cc:374:
 undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/emres/GoogleTest/./src/gtest-death-test.cc:374:
 undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/emres/GoogleTest/./src/gtest-death-test.cc:374:
 undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
```

Comment: Just there errors doesn't really give much to go on.  Can you show what the compiler/link line looks like?  What version of Google Test?

Comment: @jwernerny The latest version of GoogleTest 1.7.0. Actually i am trying to build googleTest on qnx. So i need to generate libGoogleTest_g.a and libGoogleTest.a the two libraries. I build with make command and it genaretes two .a libraries. But i think these are wrong because of naming.

Comment: Instead of making separate libraries, why not just build the combined source file (gtest-all.cc) and link it as part of your project?

Comment: Where you try to build this library???????? On the instrumental machine??? or on the target machine??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link to fix the compilation problem.
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/issues/detail?id=444
After you fixed the compilation problem, follow the below steps to create your static library files.

- Generate gtest-all.o object file for all configurations(DEBUG RELEASE) simply open QNX momentics and right click to gtest-all.cc
- Login to QNX, and copy your gtest-all.o files to any directory
- enter the directory to where files copied
- create static libraries by using ar(archive) command as shown below.

  DEBUG   : ar -rv libgoogle_test_g.a gtest-all.o

  RELEASE : ar -rv libgoogle_test.a gtest-all.o

Copy *.a files from QNX and use new static library in your project